# Como importar a fonte "Syncopate" em um SVG?

Tags: html, asp.net, xml, svg

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou trabalhando em um SVG, nele preciso usar a fonte 'Syncopate' em algumas palavras, porem não estou consigo importar para utilizar, segue as formas que tentei importar

```
<style type="text/css">      
       @font-face {
           font-family: 'Syncopate';
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 400;
           src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/syncopate/v12/pe0sMIuPIYBCpEV5eFdCBfe_.woff2) format('woff2');
           unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;

       }      
   </style>


 <style type="text/css">
       @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Syncopate');

   </style>
```

Com auxilio das respostas tentei implementar, porem no @import é tido como erro e corrompe essa parte da aplicação
[image: Com auxilio das respostas tentei implementar, porem no @import é tido como erro e corrompe essa parte da aplicação]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz uma atualização na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/538318/137387) veja se soluciona o seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Em SVG para incorporar folhas de estilos diretamente ao conteúdo use o elemento  [`<style>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style). O elemento `style` do SVG possui os mesmos atributos que o [elemento correspondente no HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style).

```html
<svg height="300" width="100%">
  <style type="text/css">
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syncopate&display=swap');
   .f1 {
     font-family: 'Syncopate';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     fill: red;
   }
 </style>

<text class="f1" x="0" y="15">
   Texto com fonte Syncopate.
</text>
```

<sup>A url para fonte desejada pode ser encontrada em https://fonts.google.com/share?selection.family=Syncopate</sup>

**EDIT**

Apesar de não estar claro na pergunta, com a edição feita pelo autor é possível identificar a mensagem de erro:

```
CS0103: o nome 'import' não existe no contexto atual.
```

Pesquisando na internet encontrei o texto [Erro do Compilador C# CS0103](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103)
Cujo a descrição:

> Houve uma tentativa de usar um nome que não existe na classe,
> namespace ou escopo. Verifique a ortografia do nome, as diretivas de
> uso e as referências de assembly para garantir que o nome que você
> está tentando usar está disponível.

Essa informação somada com tag [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) aplicada a pergunta permite inferir que o arquivo SVG em questão está inserido dentro de uma [página Razor](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).
Sendo esse o caso o Razor dá suporte a *C#* e usa o símbolo `@` para fazer a transição de *HTML* para *C#*.

Na documentação [Referência de Sintaxe de Razor](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#razor-syntax) o usuário é instruído a usar um segundo símbolo `@` para fazer o escape.

Aplicado ao exemplo anterior adicione um `@` antes do `@import`:

```html
<svg height="300" width="100%">
  <style type="text/css">
   @@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syncopate&display=swap');
   .f1 {
     font-family: 'Syncopate';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     fill: red;
   }
 </style>

<text class="f1" x="0" y="15">
   Texto com fonte Syncopate.
</text>
```